# Запись файлов на SD карту

Tags: android, java

Как записывать файлы на флеш-карту в андроиде?

Пытаюсь создать папку на флеш-карте.
Она эту папку не создает, хотя пишет, что есть такая папка при проверке, и даже если убираю sd карту, он пишет, что карта есть. Что я делаю не так?

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        File sdDir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File sdPath = new File(sdDir + "/dairy");
        Log.i(tag, sdPath.getPath());
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[[@eldqs](/users/26483/eldqs)](/users/26483/eldqs), вы даже не представляете, насколько это сложная тема - запись на SD карту в Android'е:

Если версия Андроида ниже KitKat (API < 19), то ваш код более-менее работоспособен (при условии наличия пермишенов в манифесте).

Если это не так, то тут начинаются проблемы. С одной стороны, вроде бы под KitKat запрещен доступ к внешней SD карте (ключевое слово **внешняя**, потому что есть немонтируемые внутренние SD карты, на которые это ограничение не распространяется).

Вроде бы, потому что:

1. Есть несколько более-менее успешных эксплойтов и патчей, используя которые можно обойти ограничение KitKat - погуглите с ключевыми словами: *kitkat external storage*.
2. Даже в рамках KitKat можно писать на внешнюю SD карту, при условии, что пишется каталог на внешней SD карте возвращаемый методом: [Context.getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)). Но надо учесть при этом, что этот каталог будет удаляться при сносе приложения. В принципе можно переопределять положение этого каталога, переопределив указанный метод.

Так что дерзайте.

Comment: @Barmaley Да я тоже Использую Context.getExternalDir возвращает путь на внутренней памяти а не на флешке

Comment: @eldqs внимательнее: `getExternalFilesDir()` и `getExternalFilesDirs()` - это 2 разных метода - второй возвращает список каталогов, среди которых и должен быть путь на внешнюю флешку

Comment: *оффтопик: ничего сложнее, нелаконичнее чем андроид, я ещё не видел*

Comment: @argamidon к сожалению, это болезнь всех известных платформ: сначала все просто, лаконично и логично, потом начинает обрастать разными причиндалами, появляются форки, версии, нарастают баги, патчи и проч. В конце-концов становится таким монстром, что страшно смотреть на это. Я думаю Android'у осталось жить еще лет 5, пока не появится новенькая чистенькая платформа.

Comment: Barmaley. Я с вами не согласен, хоть у Android и есть много проблем, но неактуальным он не останется никогда, даже через 10 лет он будет жить. На данный момент Android только наращивает популярность, а такая компания, как Google никогда не допустит падения этой системы, т.к. слишком много в неё было вложено. Что на счёт вопроса, то большое спасибо, пригодится

Comment: @BORSHEVIK это ваше право соглашаться или не соглашаться. Совсем, конечно, Android не умрет, но уступит место другой платформе. Android уже давно не наращивает популярность, а просто топчется на месте. Когда вы под стол пешком ходили была такая платформа J2ME, тоже была супер популярна, и где она теперь?

Comment: @Barmaley гуглил и по вашим обоим  методам пробовал, не могу ни как получить путь к sd карте.