# Запрос разрешения на сохранение в съёмном хранилище Android Java

Tags: java, android, память, android-permissions

Я хочу сделать возможность записи файлов на съёмный носитель. Дело в том, что при попытки записи на него показывает ошибку **open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)**, хотя в Манифесте реализованы разрешения

```java
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

А в коде тоже есть запросы на разрешения

```java
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
    }
```

И поэтому я думаю, что для получения доступа для записи на съёмный носитель нужно как-то реализовать это:

[image]
[image]

Но как я не знаю. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть на историю вопроса (вопроса к доступу в внешнему носителю), то история очень древняя и обильно политая кровью и потом нескольких поколений девелоперов, километрами обсуждений, миллиардами нейронов убитых в бесчисленных холиварах...

Часть дискуссий можно посмотреть например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/400359/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-sd-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83/400367#400367) и [здесь](https://www.androidpolice.com/2014/02/17/external-blues-google-has-brought-big-changes-to-sd-cards-in-kitkat-and-even-samsung-may-be-implementing-them/) или просто погуглив.

По сухому остатку сейчас картина мира выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То что вы хотите сделать, а именно писать в любой каталог флешки - как нетрудно заметить из указанной таблицы, не подпадает ни под одну категорию - следовательно запрещено.

Вы можете писать только строго в каталог, который возвращается методом `getExternalFilesDir()` или `getExternalCacheDir()` - все остальное хакинг, рутинг и фрикинг.

[Пруфлинк на документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

Comment: А если мне нужно выбрать определённый уже существующий файл на внешнем носителе и редактировать его, поможет ли getExternalFilesDir()?

Comment: Нет, не поможет... С другой стороны, смотря что понимать под редактированием. Прочитать его и записать на другой файл - так сработает, а вот модифицировать исходный файл вы не сможете

Comment: Большое спасибо. Именно это я и хотел узнать